# Certain tags cannot stand alone in questions and be viable to be answered

Tags: feature-request, tags

A select few tags cannot stand alone and those questions predominantly are asked without a related technology. When one of those questions are asked there are the inevitable comments which are applied to get the poster to add a related tag. At its core it's a time waster for all parties involved.

I put forth that certain tags cannot for the most part exist solo and require at least one other tag and the user should not be allowed to ask that question without another tag.

The question askers should either be given a message,

> Tag {x} needs a specific technology; please add it"

or require two tags minimum for specific tags.

---

For example `Regex` is used by many languages and OSs depending on usage, yet there are daily single tag `Regex` questions which go through the aforementioned cycle of people asking "What language or OS?". Rarely is there a *general* question regarding regex usage.

Same applies to certain visual graphic controls such as a the `DataGrid`. There are too many technologies with a `DataGrid` control and the user has to be prompted to update the question as well.

---

> Your proposed solution would be extremely error prone

No solution will give 100% success rate. I am simply proposing that this suggestion can lessen the current number of errors done by first time users. If a poster doesn't know what language is being used ... "Garbage In, Garbage out" motif still fully applies; and yes this will not stop all garbage.

Comment: Your example is flawed.  There are *plenty* of questions about regexes that don't immediately depend on its underlying implementation.

Comment: There is already a tooltip/suggestion box when using `regex` that gives further advice when using that tag... (same for a few other tags)... are you asking that instead of advice it's completely prohibited by some criteria?

Comment: `Rarely is there a general question regarding regex usage.`  Rarely, perhaps, but not *never*.

Comment: @Makoto, I've *never* seen a Regex question that wouldn't be better off with another additional tag. That said, I've *rarely* seen regex questions that were of any real value long term.

Comment: @JonClements the advice you mention is good but sadly not followed. I propose that it would be possible that **certain tags** instead of *just offering* advice, require action on said advice.

Comment: People will bypass this by adding random, unrelated tags. Now you're wasting the time of a lot more people.

Comment: And who decides what tags are subordinate?  And what happens when you combine two tags when neither can stand on their own?  This feature request is lacking in important implementation details.

Comment: @OmegaMan there's only so far stuff can be taken... if people won't take advice they won't. "Hey - I'm bleach... I'm used to clean out your toilet - I recommend you don't drink me...". In real life, you fail to heed that advice and you suddenly have no internal organs, on SO, your question is going to end up downvoted/closed/deleted as needs be. And who'd manage the interdependencies? That's already covered by commenting/editing and helping the OP clarify etc...

Comment: @JonClements I concur with your thoughts...but cars come with rev-limiters so the user can't blow the engine. Sure anything can be taken to extreme, but if it is known that certain tags need related tech, who is being helped by allowing a first time user to be downvoted followed by nasty comments then a closed question. *Ouch!* It appears to me (IMHO) to be a negligence on the part of SO to allow one to rev the engine over acceptable limits.  As to who manages it...who manages Tags now? The SO community. :-)

Comment: @OmegaMan It's quite easy to program a computer to not allow an engine to exceed a rev limit it can support.  It's simply not possible to program a computer to determine if a question is sensibly tagged.  If it was easy to reliably determine how a question should be tagged, with great accuracy, then it could be something to look at, but no such solution exists.

Comment: @Servy The community would determine which if any tags require another. As to programming to skip rev-limiter software; your analogy falls short, the community doesn't have access to SO code to affect changes....

Comment: @OmegaMan Stating that a given tag can't be the only tag *doesn't* accurately predict if that question is improperly tagged, nor does it have any way of correcting the problem.  Your proposed solution would be extremely error prone, with lots of false positives and lots of false negatives, and with no good resolution to the problem. You don't need to have access to SO's code base to describe how a given process could work to accomplish a given task. You were able to describe how a rev limiter works despite (I presume) not having access to the source code of the computers for all car companies.

Comment: @Servy answered to you in post.

Comment: Re: "Certain tags cannot stand alone as viable ***questions***". Don't you mean "Certain tags cannot stand alone as viable ***tags***"?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, How about this new title?

Answer (score 4):

As someone who is active in [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex), I disagree. I mostly ignore the other tags on the majority of questions.

Most questions give enough context as to which flavor they're using, in the body of the post. The popup seems to do a good enough job at that. Besides, is there any reason to tag a question with [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) if being a Python expert has little relevance to answering the question?

The other thing to note about [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) is that there are a number of things that map to it, including the "scientific" [regular-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regular-expression).

---

It would take a lot of work to decide which tags are not independent of another tag. There are thousands of pages worth of tags, so consider the amount of effort that would need to go into deciding if a tag "cannot stand alone". And what about old questions with 5 tags that "cannot stand alone"?

---

The other thing to keep in mind is that most of the singly tagged questions are asked by new users. I doubt I am alone in saying I do not trust this crowd to properly tag things.

It's more confusing when there's a completely wrong tag.